# returning a number from a <select> tag

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to get the options within a select tag to return as numbers instead of a string. This is my html:

```
 <form  #fSearchPropertiesByBedrooms (submit)="searchPropertiesByBedrooms(bathrooms)">
         <select type="number" name="bathrooms" [(ngModel)]="bathrooms">
           <option value="1">1</option>
           <option type="number" value="2">2</option>
           <option value="3">3</option>
           <option value="4">4</option>
         </select>
         <button type="submit" class="button button-primary button-xs button-green" (click)="removeSearch()">Submit</button>
       </form>
```

I thought setting type to number would do the trick but it doesn't! The function that I am using is:

```
  searchPropertiesByBedrooms(bathrooms: number) {
    console.log('bathrooms:', bathrooms);
    this.properties = this._propertyManage.searchPropertiesByBedrooms(bathrooms).valueChanges();
  }
```

However, when I use this as an input field, it does return it as a number, but for some reason, with the select tag it returns it as a string.

Comment: Try to use `[value]="3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a array of numbers and loop it using `ngFor`. Then assign the value using `[ngValue]`.

```
<select type="number" name="bathrooms" [(ngModel)]="bathrooms">
           <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item"  > {{item}}</option> 
 </select>

items: number[] = [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is `value=3`, so without the quotes.